# JQuery toggle - Animate from center instead of left side

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to toggle a division. I have the following code.

```
<body>

<div id="slide5">
    <img class="kot" src="img/kot/know-our-team.png"/>
</div>

<div id="slide6">
    // team images here
</div>

<div id="slide7">
    // division just below slide6
</div>

</body>

<script>
$(".kot").click(function(){

    $("#slide6").toggle("slow");

});
</script>
```

The problem is slide 6 "hides" by moving from right side to left side.
And slide 6 "shows" by moving from left side to right side of the screen.

I want it to appear as dropdown from center instead of appearing as an animation from left side to right side.

**UPDATE 1 -**

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/codestor/Ca7cQ/

Comment: Use fadeToggle();

$("#slide6").fadeToggle("slow");

Comment: "slide6" is not a id of element. And you used id selector(# selector).

Comment: @IshanJain Sorry, my mistake. I used id in the actual code, just made a mistake while posting it here.

Comment: @TheCuriousEngineer: Ok, no Problem. you already updated your question with correct code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`.slideToggle('slow')`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/).

Try the following code:

```
$(".kot").click(function(){
   $("#slide6").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ca7cQ/1/)